# Как вывести value у MaskedInput в Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, input, inputmask

Здравствуйте. Я уже погуглила данную проблему в интернете, но ничего из найденного (в том числе и на StackOverflow) мне не помогло. Точнее, я просто не поняла, что нужно сделать.

**Суть**: Использую MaskedInput для даты рождения:

```
<?= $form->field($modelWizards, 'age')->textInput()->label(false)->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(), [
                      'mask' => '9999-99-99',
                      'value' => Yii::$app->user->identity->age
                      ]) ?>
```

И нецелых чисел:

```
<?= $form->field($modelWizards, 'weight')->textInput(['value' => Yii::$app->user->identity->weight])->label(false)->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(), [
                          'mask' => '9{2,3}.9',
                          ]) ?>
```

Хочу из бд в инпут выводить значение (там видно, что я пыталась заполнить value в двух разных местах). Но, естественно, ничего не работает.

Что я делаю не так?

PS. В БД данные хранятся идентично маске (0000-00-00 для даты рождения и 00.0 для нецелых чисел)

Comment: можно перед полем написать: `$modelWizards->age = Yii::$app->user->identity->age;`

Comment: в БД в той же модели (modelWizards) данные, которые хотите подставлять, или в другой?

Comment: Если написать перед полем, пропадет смысл: при редактировании личных данных не хотелось бы заставлять пользователя вводить все данные заново. Данные в другой модели (user), если я, конечно, поняла, что вы имеете в виду.

Comment: так это будет тоже самое, что заполнить атрибут value

Comment: `if ($modelWizards->isNewRecord) { $modelWizards->age = Yii::$app->user->identity->age; }`

Comment: Вот это даааа! Магия, благодарю)